# How to obtain exception message to log it on catch blocks on already existing class with Javassist?

Tags: java, instrumentation, javassist

#### Case:

Try to insert a log method with a String parameter, in this case, with `e.getMessage()` on any catch Block of existing method.

The following snippets can inject a String.

```
...
CtMethod log =   CtNewMethod.make("public void log(String s){ " +
                    " System.out.println(\"Hello from injected log method \" + s); " +
                    "}",
                    ct);
ct.addMethod(log);

...
ControlFlow cf = new ControlFlow(m);
Block blocks[] = cf.basicBlocks();
for(Block block : blocks){
    Catcher catchers[] = block.catchers();
    ArrayList<Catcher> catchersList = new ArrayList<Catcher>(Arrays.asList(catchers));
    Collections.reverse(catchersList);
    for (Catcher catcher : catchersList){
        Block catchBlock = catcher.block();
        int pos = catchBlock.position();
    
        CodeIterator itr = m.getMethodInfo().getCodeAttribute().iterator();
    
        Bytecode code = new Bytecode(m.getMethodInfo().getConstPool(), 0, 0);
    
        code.addAload(0);
        code.addLdc("LogParameter");
        code.addInvokevirtual(ct,"log",log.getMethodInfo().getDescriptor());
        code.addGap(2);
        int n = itr.insertAt(pos,code.get());
    
        m.getMethodInfo().rebuildStackMapForME(cp);
    }
}
```

#### Problem

What i can't do is to get the `e.getMessage()` as input parameter to `log(String)`.

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is it true that I can handle catch block with block.catchers() method? It always return null when parsing method with catch syntax inside.

Comment: Yeap, the above code will use it to loop through catch exceptions and will inject the `log` method, previously declared and injected in the first two lines of code.

It's kinda tricky when one just start to play with it, but you will catch it later.

I marked Rafael Winterhalter's answer as the solution because I could print and check that what he was saying was true, but never could to extract the stack as a `String`, this was worked around with the base develop team, but can't remember exactly how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a catch block, you will find the exception lying on the stack. Thus, you can extract the message as follows:

- duplicate the topmost value of the stack which is the exception such that you can call methods of this object without taking away the value for deeper instructions.
- extract the message from the exception object by calling `getMessage` virtually on it.

This way, you now have the exception message lying on top of the stack.